# Difference between `cargo doc` and `cargo rustdoc`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

According to `doc.rust-lang.org`

- [`cargo rustdoc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-rustdoc.html)

> build[s] a package's documentation, using specified custom flags

- [`cargo doc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-doc.html)

> build[s] a package's documentation

What is the difference between the two? From what I understand `cargo rustdoc` is just like `cargo doc`, but it allows for more lints—for instance:

```rust
#![deny(rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links)]
```

Is this correct? Oddly enough, `cargo rustdoc` will also fail in certain situations where `cargo doc` doesn't. For instance

```
some/folder on some-branch [$!] via  v1.60.0-nightly
❯ cargo doc
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.53s

some/folder on some-branch [$!] via  v1.60.0-nightly
❯ cargo rustdoc
error: manifest path `some/folder/Cargo.toml` is a virtual manifest, but this command requires running against an actual package in this workspace
```

Also, `cargo doc` does not support adding the `-D` option, whereas `cargo rustdoc` does.

```
❯ cargo doc -- -D rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links
error: Found argument '-D' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    cargo doc [OPTIONS]

For more information try --help
```

Comment: It looks like `rustdoc` is for building a single target's docs, whereas `doc` is for building a whole package's docs. Not sure when you'd ever want the former over the latter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Their relationship is like between `cargo build` and `cargo rustc`: `cargo doc` performs all the usual work, for an entire workspace, including dependencies (by default). `cargo rustdoc` allows you to pass flags directly to rustdoc, and only works for a single crate.

[Here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/0655dd25a0242c56eb51faecc86dd67a5abfb8dd/src/bin/cargo/commands/rustdoc.rs#L41-L61) is the execution code for `cargo rustdoc`. [Here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/0655dd25a0242c56eb51faecc86dd67a5abfb8dd/src/bin/cargo/commands/doc.rs#L42-L57) is the code for `cargo doc`. The only differences is that `cargo rustdoc` always specify to not check dependencies while `cargo doc` allows you to choose (by default it does, but you can specify the flag `--no-deps`), and that `cargo rustc` allows you to pass flags directly to rustdoc with the flags after the `--`.